# How can I allow a plugin to expose a WPF or WindowsForms control through a common property?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, .net-4.0

I am currently developing an application that allows the use of plugins. One of the features is that the plugin could expose a settings UI that the hosting application would embed somewhere for the user to see.

What I am wondering is if there is some way that I can add a property to my plugin interface that will allow a plugin developer to create either a wpf or winforms UI and expose it through this property while keeping the property typed? (ie. not using "object" as the property type), or without the use of seperate properties (ie. WPFUI, WinFormsUI) etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two technologies work very differently.  I would recommend either exposing a [Windows.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) or a [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx), but not both (at least not from the *same* plugin API).

If you expose a `Control`, it's simple for a WPF control to be served up using an [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Likewise, a `FrameworkElement` can be provided by a Windows Forms plugin via a [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

My decision here would be more in terms of how the host application is developed.  If you're using WPF, I would strongly recommend exposing the plugin as a `FrameworkElement`, as this provides you a lot more flexibility.  If your main application is going to be Windows Forms based, then just exposing a `Control` is simple.

If you don't want this added complexity, I'd actually recommend two separate APIs - one for Windows Forms users and one for WPF users, as this keeps the simplicity on the end users' part the same.  Depending on the plugin mechanism, this is typically fairly simple to provide.

Comment: Well currently the main application is developed using WPF which you'd think would make my decision easy. However, the library is open source and was written with the idea that a person could easily just use the parts of the application it liked, and write their own portions of things they don't like, like the UI.. so somebody could get bored one day and write a UI in windows forms because they don't like how I made the wpf one. I'm hoping that to a plugin it wouldn't matter what the host is, as long as the host ensures it provides the proper hosting mechanisms (type checking etc).

Comment: I even checked the inheritance tree to see if they implement any of the same interfaces.. apparently they do not

Comment: @SilverX No- they're really completely separate.  If your app is WPF, I'd expose it via WPF.  It's easy to wrap Win Forms content into a `WindowsFormsHost`, but exposing via WPF gives you more control in the host for composability, etc.